# Uniqueness of solution of concave down function

Tags: analysis

I have a function $f :(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ as the sum of two functions $g$ and $h$.
$$
f(x)=g(x)+h(x), 
$$
I have shown that f has at least one solution by using the intermediate value Theorem.
Now, I am looking for the uniqueness of the solution ( I know that $g$ is a concave-down function and $h$ is a decreasing function).

Is there any approach to get the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ has at least one solution?" Do you mean that equation $f(x)=0$ has at least one solution?

Comment: if by solution you mean root, there are many counter examples. Assume $g(x)=-x^2$ which is a concave function and $h(x)=-x$ which is a decreasing function. $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$ and $x=-1$ as solutions which means the root is not unique.